# Writing a JOIN in EntityFramework method syntax

Tags: entity-framework, join

I have the following join:

```
 var orders = from o in DB.Orders
              join od in DB.OrderDetails on o.OrderId equals od.OrderId
              where od.Active == 1
              && od.Date > dateFrom
              && od.StatusCode == 5
              && o.CompanyId == companyId 
              select o;
```

I'm trying to rewrite it using the method syntax.

```
var orders = DB.Orders.Join(DB.OrderDetails,
             o => OrderId,
             od => OrderId,
             (o, od) => ...
```

where I put the three dots is where I start to get fuzzy. I want to retrieve only the Order (the whole order), not the OrderDetails. But I need to query OrderDetails in my conditions. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Why not use a navigation property to express the relationship? Explicit joining of entities should only ever be needed for loosely related tables which cannot have a traditional dedicated FK relationship.

Comment: OK, you got me. I don't know how to write it with navigation properties either.

Comment: Depending on who set up the entities, they may be there already. In the Order entity class, is there a property for the OrderDetail? (I.e. `public virtual OrderDetail  OrderDetail { get; set; }`)

Comment: So you had something like this in mind?
var orders = DB.Orders.Where(o => o.CompanyId == companyId 
            && o.OrderDetails.Any(od => od.Active == 1 && od.Date > dateFrom && od.StatusCode == 5));

Comment: Yep, and then you can use `Select` to retrieve details from both Order and OrderDetails as needed, or if you want the Order and Details entities to edit, use `Include(o.OrderDetails)` to ensure it's populated with the Order(s) retrieved. The beauty of navigation properties is letting EF handle the SQL rather than substituting writing SQL with trying to write Linq expressions, Fluent or Linqish.